Two computers on the same subnet at a certain point can't talk, but both still ping the outside world
I have a strange issue with network connections in the scenario described below:

a computer A, MacBook 19" late 2019 running Sonoma 14.7.1
a computer B, Huawei MateBook D 14 Laptop, running PureOS 10 (uname -a gives Linux 5.10.0-33-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.226-1 (2024-10-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux)
— both computers are connected to a WiFi, same subnet (but, see below, the same problem happens in another scenario with different networking gear).

The symptom is that after a few minutes (say 20-30) existing connections between A and B  fail (for the record, a long rsync session). To investigate the problem I've set up:

a ping from A to B and one from to B to A and they fail when the error shows up, telling "destination unreachable"
a ping to 8.8.8.8 from both computers and these NEVER fail

So the simple answer that the network card of B is defective doesn't work because B is always able to ping the external world, while apparently only the A <-> B connections fail. A tail -F on both system.log and messages on B shows nothing relevant to the network.
Usually after a couple of minutes the A <-> B ping resumes with no intervention, but in the meantime rsync failed. Manually restarting the network system on B also restores the connection.
At first I suspected something related to the network equipment outside the two laptops, but the same thing happens also in a different (more complex) scenario, with another WiFi equipment and B connected by cable through a monitor hub. So I'm really puzzled at this point.
Thanks.

Try setting static ARP mappings between the two laptops and see if that makes the problem go away. If it does, it's a sign that ARP is breaking, probably because multicast/broadcast is breaking. Handling multicast/broadcast is tricky over Wi-Fi, and many products have buggy implementations. If this turns out to be the case, there are some things you can do to make your buggy Wi-Fi devices less likely to hit the bugs. (Your Mac is probably not at fault, because Apple is careful with their multicast implementations because it's critical to Bonjour which is critical to the Apple ecosystem.)
